# Finding the temperature of a gas using the $P$-$V$ diagram

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics, pressure, temperature, ideal-gas

I need to know a way to relate the P-V curve of an ideal gas to its temperature.I found a similar question on stackexchange but couldn't understand how the relationship between a point and the adiabatic curve drawn there gives us an idea about the temperature of the gas .
If you can explain it using the below graph it will be much easier.

I need to compare the temperatures at A,B,C.
[image: diagram]